# Syntax Coloring - Eclipse CDT

Tags: java, colors, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am implementing an Eclipse plugin for C programmers (I am using Eclipse IDE Luna) and I need to color some syntax in the editor(I have a locations of variables that I need to color but I can't find a way to color these variables).
Is there functions that can I use to do that ?
I appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: If you need a built-in feature inside Eclipse, please tell us which version of Eclipse you use.

Comment: I edited the post.. I am using Eclipse IDE Luna. @LaurentHermand